# Spawn specific objects from table in for loop - Corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have a table of objects that I spawn into a scrollview space, but at the moment its picking randomly when I would actually like to actually spawn in specific sets, for example: 
[1] [2] [3] [1] [2] [3] [1] [2] [3] across the loop number.

I understand it would be something to do with removing the math.random to spawn 1 random object from the table, but I'm not sure how I could code it to do it in order of the table instead. Maybe its something simple I missed.

**spawn table**

```
local colorsData = { 
{name = "Blue", img = "images/RectangleBlue@2x.png"},
{name = "Red", img = "images/RectangleRed@2x.png"},
{name = "Green", img = "images/RectangleGreen@2x.png"}
}
```

**For loop**

```
local spaceApart = 100
for idx = 1,11 do
    local c = math.random(1, #colorsData) 
    local cd = colorsData[c]
    local s = display.newImageRect(cd.img, 106,60)
    s.name = cd.name
    s.x = (idx * spaceApart)
    s.y = (scrollView.height / 2) 
    physics.addBody(s, { isSensor = true })
    s:addEventListener ("tap", levelTapped)
    scrollView:insert(s)
end
```

Comment: You can change the assignment for `c` to be `c = idx%3~= 0 and idx%3 or 3`

Comment: Hi @DigitalVeer: What does that % sign mean in LUA? Ive not come across using it so far?

Comment: % is a mathematical operation called the modulus which returns the remainder of the division. It is often used in these types of cases.

Comment: Oh ok, I see now. Thanks guys :)

Comment: Hey sorry to bring this up again, I am running into an issue with the code above. I have removed scrollView and instead stored it in a display group which I then link to an event listener to drag the entire group. Though I wish the spawns from above table had their own physics body, I have noticed the collisions isn't working correctly. Is this a problem with dragging entire display groups even though the objects inside are unique?